# Need to remove the title from a specific magento category page

Tags: magento

## The problem

I need to remove the category name or title from specific non-product category pages but can't find the reference or block names to remove it with layout updates. I have already found the code that I could override and comment out to remove the title from every category page but that won't work since I need the title on most category pages.

## What I'm trying to do

In the past I've been able to turn on the template path hints with block names, spend a second researching and found a great way to remove a block. This is the kind of code I have used before:

```
<reference name="Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs">
   <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</reference>
```

## TL;DR

I just need a simple way to remove the category title name from specific categories. If my idea about update xml is junk I'll take any suggestions. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by creating a custom module, overriding the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View` block and doing something like this:

In `app/local/Yournamespace/Titlemodule/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<!-- .... -->
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <titlemodule>
                <class>Yournamespace_Titlemodule_Block</class>
            </titlemodule>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>Yournamespace_Titlemodule_Block_Category_View</product_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

and in `app/local/Yournamespace/Titlemodule/Block/Category/View.php`

```
class Yournamespace_Titlemodule_Block_Category_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();  // if needed
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        // custom logic here
        $headBlock->setTitle($this->__('New title, or none'));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

It will give you plenty of possibilities running custom logic before manipulating any blocks on the page.